# check uhd version in Fedora

Tags: centos6.5, uhd

I know how to check the version of UHD in Ubuntu ($ dpkg -s uhd), what is the corresponding command in CentOS 6.5?

Besides, if I want to update the current UHD by uhd_003.009.002-release_Fedora-21-x86_64.rpm in the following link: http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd/latest_release/, what is the corresponding commands in Fedora for the following:

sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd/repo/uhd/ubuntu/`lsb_release -cs` `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ettus.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -t `lsb_release -cs` uhd

Comment: Hi Cindy, these are more administrative than programming questions; also, the first one is a universal Fedora question, and not very related to UHD. I don't think stack overflow is the best place to discuss them. Are you already member of the usrp-users mailing list community? [Sign up] (http://lists.ettus.com/mailman/listinfo/usrp-users_lists.ettus.com) and discuss in free form :)

Answer (score 0):

Fedora is using `rpm` package manager. You can get information about installed version using:

```
rpm -q uhd
```

and search for available versions of `uhf` using

```
dnf list uhd
```